# Is it possible to host an AngularJS app on Amazon S3 using CloudFront over SSL?

Tags: angularjs, ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm not aware of a solution that allows you to do this using SSL on CloudFront simply because it cannot pull from S3 over SSL. Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you specifically wanting the communication between CloudFront and S3 to use SSL? Or do you just want all resources loaded in the browser, and all requests made by Angular, to use SSL?

Comment: @MarkB the browser has to load the app over SSL in order for features such as WebRTC to work properly.  If CloudFront loads from S3 over HTTP and then delivers to the client over HTTPS, will that work?  Or does that break the SSL chain?

Comment: It will work fine since the browser only knows that it is loading the files over SSL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You can require your CloudFront content to be served via HTTPS to your viewers, and *separately* have CloudFront pull from your origin via HTTP **or** HTTPS. See [Using an HTTPS Connection to Access Your Objects](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/SecureConnections.html)

That document states:

> For web distributions, you can use HTTPS requests to ensure that your
>   objects are encrypted when CloudFront serves them to viewers and,
>   optionally, when CloudFront gets the objects from your origin.

The viewer <== CloudFront is one connection, and the CloudFront <== Originis another separate connection.

Its up to you whether or not you need SSL end to end, but there is no limitation like the one you describe.

Comment: This is the correct answer, thank you.  For those falling into the same trap as I did, make sure you set the origin to be the actual endpoint of the S3 bucket, not the internal suggested one, and also make sure you force the Origin Protocol Policy to be HTTP Only, do not Match Viewer.